# Applying the Cesaro-Stolz Theorem recursively

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have fo find: $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigg(1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)$$

using the [Cesaro-Stolz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Applying what the theorem states once i get: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}$

My question is: can i apply it again to get: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=0$?

Comment: Yes, why not? If this new exercise was a completely new exercise, wouldn't you had solved it with S-C? Then, why would the fact that this is not a new exercise, but part of a larger one change your technique?

Comment: Well in school they never tell us what freedom we have while doing math, so i was unsure. I thought logically its possible, i just wanted to be sure.

Comment: BTW if you use SC, the new limit should be $\lim_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Comment: Another super-quick solution to the second problem (now that this has been dredged up): show that $S(n)=1+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}$ can be bounded from below by $Cn\sqrt{n}$ for some constant $C$ (hint: consider only the terms from $\sqrt{n/2}$ forward; how many of them are there, and how big must they be?) and then see what that means for the limit of $(n+1)/S(n)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S-C is the easiest way to calculate

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}$$

If you want an alternate solution, note that

$$1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} \,,$$

and

$$\lim_n \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} =\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} dx \,.$$

Then

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} }=0$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative method, but you could use something like:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\sqrt{i}\Bigg)^{-1}$$
I would definitely recommend to switch the order of the terms (although it might seem weird since you are looking $\infty\to 1$).

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)=$
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}+\frac{n-1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}}+1\Bigg)$

Now, this looks a bit 'more recursive' (:

$=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}+\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\Bigg)$

$=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot\underbrace{\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\sqrt{i}\Bigg)^{-1}}_{{\to 0}\;\forall k=0,\ldots n-1}=0$